# python and shell for loop combined extrange behaviour

Tags: python, bash, for-loop

I have a simple python script to rename my data: wchich has worked for one file:

```
for line in Coord:
    coord = line.split()[0]
    miRname = line.split()[1]
    print miRname
    os.system('samtools view -h ' + BAMfile + ' '+ coord + ' >' + miRname) #extract the reads from a coordinate
    os.system("sed -i 's/HISEQ2500/" + miRname + "/g' " + miRname)  #'samtools view -H ' + miRname + ' >' + 'header.sam') #extract headers frm the bam
    os.system('samtools fastq ' + miRname + ' >>' + Treatment)
    os.system('rm ' + miRname )
```

Now I wanted to parse over a folder using shell (because that is what I know how to use easily for this case):

```
MAPPINGS_DIR=/abc/defg/hij
for bam in $MAPPPINGS_DIR/mappings/tophat2.1.1/*; do
    name=$(basename $bam);
    echo $name
    python ~/Documents/scripts/miRNA_reads_prep.py MAPPINGS_DIR$bam/$name.bam name.fastq
done
```

I got the problem that this started overwriting my original file (bam-> happily the copy of it), while checking what this for loop is doing:
is grabbing as a second argument all the list of all the bam files, therefore my sys2 is my second bam file (the copy one)

```
ENSG00000199075 ENSG00000273874 homo_sapiens_GRCh84_BC.sorted.miRNA.GTF Mock_24_1 Mock_24_1.fastq mature.fa mature.fa.gz miRBase.gff miRcoord miRNAseq.fa sedBtFKZ7 sedFFMTf1 sedHt4fBN sedIZagSr sedM9Wbvy sedout7Bz try
ENSG00000278267
samtools view -h /mappings/tophat2.1.1/Mock_24h_1/Mock_24h_1.bam 1:17369-17436 >ENSG00000278267
sed -i 's/HISEQ2500/ENSG00000278267/g' ENSG00000278267
samtools fastq ENSG00000278267 >>/mappings/tophat2.1.1/Mock_24h_1/Mock_24h_1.sorted.bam
rm ENSG00000278267
['/print/miRNA_reads_prep.py', '/mappings/tophat2.1.1/Mock_24h_1/Mock_24h_1.bam', '/mappings/tophat2.1.1/Mock_24h_1/Mock_24h_1.sorted.bam', '/mappings/tophat2.1.1/Mock_24h_1/unmapped.bam', '/mappings/tophat2.1.1/Mock_24h_2/Mock_24h_2.bam', '/mappings/tophat2.1.1/Mock_24h_2/Mock_24h_2.sorted.bam', '/mappings/tophat2.1.1/Mock_24h_2/unmapped.bam', '/mappings/tophat2.1.1/Mock_24h_3/Mock_24h_3.bam', '/mappings/tophat2.1.1/Mock_24h_3/Mock_24h_3.sorted.bam', '/mappings/tophat2.1.1/Mock_24h_3/unmapped.bam', '/mappings/tophat2.1.1/Mock_3h_1/Mock_3h_1.bam', '/mappings/tophat2.1.1/Mock_3h_1/Mock_3h_1.sorted.bam', '/mappings/tophat2.1.1/Mock_3h_1/unmapped.bam', '/mappings/tophat2.1.1/Mock_3h_2/Mock_3h_2.bam', '/mappings/tophat2.1.1/Mock_3h_2/Mock_3h_2.sorted.bam', '/mappings/tophat2.1.1/Mock_3h_2/unmapped.bam',  'Mock_24_1.fastq']
```

I would like to know how to correct this in my for loop?
should I do a second for loop for each internal folder? I thought that in every round of the for loop checks each argument.

Comment: there is a typo `bam in $MAPPPINGS_DIR` three P instead of two.. not sure if it in your code or just here in SO...

Comment: Try to use `os.system` as little as possible. For example, you can call `os.remove` instead of forking a new process to run the external `rm` command. Also, use the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system`.

Comment: Thank you! Both comments are really useful. I did not notice that typo.

Answer (score 0):

there is a typo `bam in $MAPPPINGS_DIR` three P instead of two... – sp asic